# Why grid becomes inappropriate in 3D projection after assigning x and yticks?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, z-axis

Using the following code grid doesn't appear properly as it can be seen in the figure that the squares in the xy plane have large size as compared to z axis. how can I get the grid of equal boxes? I have observed the grid squares are equal when I don't apply x and yticks. Can I fix this error?

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
x= np.linspace(-math.pi,math.pi,30)
y= np.linspace(-math.pi,math.pi,30)
xx,yy = np.meshgrid(x,y)

X_grid, Y_grid = np.meshgrid(x,y)
print("X_grid shape: ",X_grid.shape)
zz =-2*(np.cos(xx) + np.cos(yy))

ax = plt.axes(projection='3d')

ax.plot_surface(xx,yy,zz)

plt.xticks([x[0],x[int(len(s)/2)], x[-1]], [r'$-\pi$',  r'$0$', r'$-\pi$' ])
plt.yticks([y[0],y[int(len(s)/2)], y[-1]], [r'$-\pi$',  r'$0$', r'$-\pi$' ])
plt.xlabel("kx")
plt.ylabel("ky")
```

[image]

Comment: Is there anything unclear in this explanation?

Comment: you may try ticking the "major" axis (using ax.set_major_locator called with ticker.MultipleLocator(math.pi)) and griding the "minor" axis (using ax.grid(True, which="minor")).

Comment: Check the code now please,finally got it working! and of course if you don't want grid remember using `ax.grid(False)`.

Answer (score 0):

Referring to the [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/tutorial.html) I found this:

> Note: Prior to version 1.0.0, the method of creating a 3D axes was different. For those using older versions of matplotlib, change ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d') to ax = Axes3D(fig).

See this for [.set_zticks](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.axes3d.Axes3D.html#mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.axes3d.Axes3D.set_zticks). Note that since this is 3D plot so this documentation is found in `mplot3d`

So modified the code accordingly.

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np 
import math
import os
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
x= np.linspace(-math.pi,math.pi,30)
y= np.linspace(-math.pi,math.pi,30)
z= np.linspace(-math.pi,math.pi,30)

xx,yy = np.meshgrid(x,y)

X_grid, Y_grid = np.meshgrid(x,y)
print("X_grid shape: ",X_grid.shape)
zz =-2*(np.cos(X_grid) + np.cos(Y_grid))

Z = zz.reshape(X_grid.shape)

ax = Axes3D(fig)

#updated lines
ax.set_zticks([z[0],z[int(len(z)/2)], z[-1]])
ax.set_zticklabels([r'$-\pi$',  r'$0$', r'$-\pi$' ])

plt.xticks([x[0],x[int(len(x)/2)], x[-1]], [r'$-\pi$',  r'$0$', r'$-\pi$' ])
plt.yticks([y[0],y[int(len(y)/2)], y[-1]], [r'$-\pi$',  r'$0$', r'$-\pi$' ])

plt.xlabel("kx")
plt.ylabel("ky")    
ax.plot_surface(X_grid,Y_grid,Z)
```

Comment: I tried these changes but it doesn't effect the grid. Still the xy splane contains big squares as compared to z axis

Comment: My main problem is to get the grid of equal squares.

Comment: See [this](https://imgur.com/2gKygjK). Let us know if still your problem persists.

Comment: Yes it gives right grid. But I want to label xticks from $-\pi$ to $\pi$ so I define xticklabels which change grid.

Comment: you want the same range on `z` axis as well as the `xy` axis  ?

Comment: Yes But I want to use xtick and yticks such that it doesn't effect the grids

Comment: or is there anyways to remove the lines of the grid?

Comment: Yes, there is just use `ax.grid(False)`